# Does facebooks new open graph api allow for filtering by location?

Tags: facebook

I see that www.booshaka.com allows you to search public facebook updates via the new api.. I wondered if it would be possible to include a filter.. much like on twitter "QUERY near:LOCATION" etc..

Answer (score 0):

We don't attach location information to Status Updates, so it's not a searchable field.

The only location search you can do is look for places -

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`

Comment: So since this question was answered, 'posts' in the graph API now *does* include a place.  So is this possible now?